# Shiny to Markdown PDF Fails on Second and Subsequent Runs

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I've been trying to follow this tutorial: [generating reports](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html)

I've been able to get the suggested code to run successfully and produces PDFs without issue. When I try to run the Shiny app using my own `.Rmd` file, it works fine the first time and produces a PDF where desired. On the second and any additional runs, the file generation fails with `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'.`

I've tried mentioning the {float} package in the YAML header of the markdown file without any improvement. The only success seems to be removing all of the `r` code blocks, which leaves my document looking pretty sparse.

Here is **app.R**:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    dateInput("dateinput", "Select a date"),
    downloadButton("report.pdf", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report.pdf <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "deviants.Rmd")
        file.copy("deviants.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        params <- list(n = input$slider, d = input$dateinput)
        print(class(params$n))
        print(class(params$d))
        print(params)

        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

and **deviants.Rmd**:

````
---
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  n: NA
  d: NA
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \subsectionfont{\centering}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
- \usepackage{float{
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(grid)
library(png)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat(params$n)
cat(params$d)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
sampleMetrics <- data.frame(
  Sample = c("Threshold","A","2","4","11","C","DEF"),
  Length = c(">= 6", 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12),
  Experiment1 = c(">= 10000",5696,8006,6675,9477,5028,7093),
  Experiment2 = c(">= 10000", 21223, 27890, 34623, 24152, 25716, 45187),
  Sum = c(">=20000", 28409, 41895, 46181, 34129, 12244, 51910),
  Total1 = c("N/A", 41382, 132670, 78271, 89930, 98788, 13015),
  Total2 = c("N/A", 43170, 53280, 57568, 46584, 51156, 55045),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

super_cell_spec <- function(data, threshold) {
  cell_spec(as.numeric(data), "latex", background = ifelse(
    as.numeric(data) >= threshold, "#45ff41", "#ff4242"))
}
sampleMetrics$Length[-1] <- super_cell_spec(sampleMetrics$Length[-1], 6)
sampleMetrics$Experiment1[-1] <- super_cell_spec(
   sampleMetrics$Experiment1[-1], 10000)
sampleMetrics$Experiment2[-1] <- super_cell_spec(
   sampleMetrics$Experiment2[-1], 10000)
sampleMetrics$Sum[-1] <- super_cell_spec(sampleMetrics$Sum[-1], 20000)

sampleMetrics[1,] <- cell_spec(sampleMetrics[1,], "latex", 
   background = "#afafaf")

sampleMetrics%>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = F, escape = F, 
        col.names = linebreak(c("Sample",
          "Length", "Experiment 1", 
          "Experiment 2","Sum",
          "Total\n1", "Total\n2"), 
          align = "c")) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```
````

I definitely wouldn't be as confused if it didn't work flawlessly the first time around. Maybe something to do with the `envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())` in **app.R**? Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Delete the created file and run the program again in the same session, let me know what happens.

Comment: How did you try to load `float.sty`? Can you process the `Rmd` directly? Please minimize your example, i.e. remove everything that is not needed to produce the error.

Comment: @Chabo that doesn't appear to help, good idea though.

@RalfStubner Editing now, it can be narrowed down to the last code block. Edited YAML to load float as well, and the file can definitely be knit normally. Received the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.124 \multirow` with float package loaded.

Comment: After doing some more digging, it appears that a lot of errors take place when loading packages. I've had to load latex packages like multirow and float in order to squash these, but am still getting an `! Undefined control sequence` error. Do kable and kable_extra not load these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by adding additional packages, mostly through the trial and error of `! Undefined control sequence` errors. It would report an issue with `multirow` and I would look up the right latex package to include.

In the end, my YAML Rmarkdown header looked like:

```
---
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  d: NA
  st: NA
header-includes:
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{makecell, tabularx, float, multirow, pgfplots}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \subsectionfont{\centering}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
---
```

This fixed the problem.